# WinRT How to check internet connection?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, internet-connection

I use this function to check internet connection

```
public static bool IsConnectedToInternet()
{
  ConnectionProfile connectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
  return (connectionProfile != null && connectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess);
}
```

and it works fine if i am not connected to a network, but the problem appear when internet down and still connected this method return true.
Is there another way to check internet connection perfectrly?

Comment: Define "internet connection". You either can reach some host(s) or not, that's the only thing you should care about and present nice error messages when host is not reachable.

Answer (score 1):

That is the right API to use. But as Daniel said connectivity to the internet can mean a lot of things. Also note there is latency in detecting the loss and gain of the "internet connection".

It is possible to create a background task that will be invoked when the network connectivity is detected as InternetAvailable; see SystemTriggerType.